# MarkLogic 8 Search case insensitive in the JSON elements - XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Present records

```
{"myLabel":"AFRICANA"}
{"myLabel":"africans"}
{"myLabel":"AFRICAN"}
{"myLabel":"Africa"}
```

Query : `cts:json-property-word-match("myLabel", "Africa*")`

Result: 

    {"myLabel":"Africa"}


Query returns only match case data not all relavent rows.

Query : `cts:json-property-word-match("myLabel", "Africa*", "case-insensitive")`

Result: 
    your query returned an empty sequence

If I use "case-insensitive" option it returns empty sequence.

I have set word lexicons as myLabel.
How do I search for JSON data case insensitively?

Comment: You may want to specify which of the entries shown is in fact returned by your query.  If your problem is that the second entry is not being returned, bear in mind that its third letter is a T not an R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the examples provided return the expected results for me. Did you intend to show the second query as a search with [`cts:json-property-value-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:json-property-value-query)?

If that is the case, then applying the `wildcarded` option will ensure that values are matched case-insenstive and as a wildcarded query:

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:json-property-value-query("myLabel", "Africa*", ("wildcarded","case-insensitive")))
```

Double check to see if you have "trailing wildcard searches" enabled, or any of the three, two, or one character searches enabled for your content database. The [rules for wildcard searches](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard#id_61953) state that you need specific database indexes enabled for the query to automatically apply queries with wildcard patters as a wildcarded query:

> If neither "wildcarded" nor "unwildcarded" is present, the database configuration and $text determine wildcarding. If the database has any wildcard indexes enabled ("three character searches", "two character searches", "one character searches", or "trailing wildcard searches") and if $text contains either of the wildcard characters '?' or '*', it specifies "wildcarded". Otherwise it specifies "unwildcarded".

With either of those index settings enabled, a query term with a `*` should automatically execute as a wildcard query, and you can remove the explicit `wildcarded` option:

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:json-property-value-query("myLabel", "Africa*", "case-insensitive"))
```

Comment: First of all thanks for response. I am able to find expected response using this query **cts:json-property-value-query**. `cts:search(doc(),cts:json-property-value-query("myLabel", "Africa*", ("wildcarded","case-insensitive")))` I thnik i was missing "wildcarded" option as well.